# Tests don't run because typescript throws error when trying to test type checking

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, types, jestjs

Trying to test to make sure that a typed variable can only be assigned certain values. Is there a way to use jest to throw an error if an invalid value is assigned, without typescript preventing the tests from running and throwing an error before tests run?

```
In class constructor:
defaultValue: string | null

In test:
expect(() => instance.defaultValue = 100).toThrow()
```

I expect that the test should run and acknowledge that this does throw an error, but the error is thrown before the test runs, preventing all tests from running.

Comment: You're intention here could be described as a desire to verify that the TypeScript compiler works.

Comment: In other words, would you say that this test isn't really worth writing? @Pointy

Comment: I mean that sort of verification is a good thing for *somebody*, like Microsoft maybe or whoever's responsible for TypeScript nowadays, but I'm not sure it makes a lot of sense for an application that happens to be based on TypeScript.

Answer (score 5):

Typescript is not a runtime type checker, it is a compile time type checker. This means that all types are checked before the code is converted to javascript and if there is a type error the compile fails. If your class takes data from an unverified source, IE an API you cannot check that with typescript.

Your test implies 1 of 2 things:

Either Your constructor is meant to consume data that is only known at runtime, but should always be a string and must throw an error if it is not.  In that case you may cast your class to `any` this removes type checking completely for this object, but it will allow you test that your class throws an error.

```
const instance = new (MyClass as any)(42) // throws an error
```

Or your class is only used by data the developer explicitly provides to it and your test only verifies that typescript will not allow a developer to make a mistake. In that case, this is not a useful test and you should probably remove it.